# Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type via nested type

Tags: c#, save, picturebox, preview

This is code will add Save Tool Tip in the for print preview and also saving the picturebox as a PDF format.

```
 class SavePrint : System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog
        {
            public SavePrint()
                : base()
            {
                if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("toolstrip1"))
                {

                    ToolStrip tStrip1 = (ToolStrip)this.Controls["toolstrip1"];
                    ToolStripButton button1 = new ToolStripButton();
                    button1.Text = "Save";

                    button1.Click += new EventHandler(SaveDocument);
                    button1.Visible = true;
                    tStrip1.Items.Add(button1);


                }
            }

            public void SaveDocument(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.Title = "Save As PDF";
                sfd.Filter = "PDF|*.pdf";
                sfd.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";

                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image);//GETTING THE ERROR HERE
                    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

                    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
                    doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
                    XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);

                    xgr.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
                    doc.Save(sfd.FileName);
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

im getting the error at this line "Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image)" what should i do so it can inherit my pictureBox?

Comment: you may want to post the error or exception details so someone can provide some help.  you may want to check if the pictureBox.Image is null.

Comment: where is pictureBox defined?

Comment: Its located inside public partial class Form1 : Form

Comment: A [nested class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) is not a subclass.  It's a class that can access private members of its container class, but is otherwise independent.  To access *instance* properties of a container class, pass the container to the constructor of the nested class.

Comment: i really have no idea, i'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the constructor of your class `SavePrint` to have the following signature:

```
    class SavePrint : System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog
    {
        readonly Form1 parent;
        public SavePrint(Form1 parent)
            : base()
        {
            this.parent = parent;

            // Remainder as before
        }
    }
```

Then when you construct your `SavePrint`, pass the appropriate instance `Form1` in to the constructor.

```
            SavePrint savePrint = new SavePrint(this);
```

Having done that, your `SavePrint` will be able to access its fields and properties:

```
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(parent.pictureBox.Image);
```

By the way, you should wrap all of your [disposables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements, like so:

```
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(parent.pictureBox.Image))
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
            }
```

Comment: what is the effect if it's not wrapped?

Comment: @KevinRodriguez - unmanaged resources held by the class (windows handles, bitmap data, etc) will not be immediately freed, which can cause out-of-memory problems down the road unless the garbage collector kicks in soon enough.

Comment: If the class implements the [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, you should wrap it in a `using` statement.  Most classes don't, however many [`System.Drawing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`System.Windows.Forms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and file-related classes do.  (DIsposing a file closes the file, e.g.)  If you think a class might be disposable, check the documentation, or try putting it in a `using` statement.